# Where can I find java examples for zeromq over TLS?

Tags: java, ssl, zeromq

I am looking for java examples that show me how to use zeromq over TLS. I found a working c++ example in https://github.com/ianbarber/TLSZMQ so it appears that the zeromq libraries support TLS.

However, I haven't been able to find any java examples with TLS. It would really be nice if these examples show me how to load the certificates into the keystore using keytool but I can probably figure that part out if I can just see some working example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some searching I get the sense there aren't any java TLS ZeroMQ examples as of today (Aug 7, 2013). Support for TLS is not a built-in functionality of the ZeroMQ libraries. There is a branch that supports TLS from Wes Young, but it has not been integrated into the main ZeroMQ trunk and the latest commit was a year ago.  The C++ example https://github.com/ianbarber/TLSZMQ is more of a proof of concept and has limitations such as it cannot be used in a publish subscribe model. Given the immaturity of TLS support in ZeroMQ I think it would be wise to pursue other security options.

Answer (score 0):

The latest info on ZeroMq and encryption is here:

http://zeromq.org/topics:encryption

Comment: I found that page as well. Unfortunately it does not contain any java examples on how to use zeromq over TLS.